# How to convert pCO2 (uatm) in seawater to grams

Tags: gas-laws, ideal-gas

I have seawater pCO2 measurements, and I need to convert them from uatm to moles or grams for around a 50m depth integration.
I know the solubility coefficient and temperature among other data.

For example, I have:

- 445.87uatm seawater pCO2
- 2.77*10<sup>-5</sup>  (mol atm<sup>-1</sup> m<sup>-3</sup>) solubility coefficient
- 50 m Hypothetical integration depth
- 12 (carbon to mole conversion)

The air-sea flux equation is F=delta pCO2 (atm) * solubility (mol atm<sup>-1</sup> m<sup>-3</sup>)  * gas transfer velocity (m / yr)
Which gives an answer in mol / m2 / year.

To calculate the total volume of carbon in grams, can I use:
pCO2 (uatm) * 1 000 000 (atm) * solubility  (mol atm<sup>-1</sup> m<sup>-3</sup>) * integration depth (m) * 12 (to convert to grams). And then if I had a time component, divide by the number of days to get (g/m2/day).

This gives:

(445.87*1 000 000)*2.77e<sup>-5</sup>*50*12 =  7410359.39 (gC / m2)  or 7410.36 kgC/m2.

Is this correct? Is the integration depth a valid assumption in replacing gas transfer velocity? 
Is using the solubility the correct way to calculate this mass using Henrys' Law?
Can you point me in any resources to check these calculations?

Thanks very much.

Comment: The solubility coefficient seems to me to be an error. It is only 1.2 mg /m3 for pure CO2. BTW, It is better to stay in algebraic equation form as long as you can, plugging in numbers in the last minute. Correctness or mistakes are easier to be seen.

Comment: I'm a bit befuddled about what you are doing, but I'd expect the solubility coefficient to be affected by pH, temperature and salinity.